# Truncate short Description with “Read More” toggle in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to toggle WooCommerce product description with a read more link. I'm having issues with code I'm using and don't know where to problem lies.

Here is the code I'm using in my `functions.php` in the child theme

```php
/**
 * @snippet       Truncate Short Description @ WooCommerce Single
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.9
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_short_description_truncate_read_more' );
function bbloomer_woocommerce_short_description_truncate_read_more() { 
   wc_enqueue_js('
      var show_char = 40;
      var ellipses = "... ";
      var content = $(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description").html();
      if (content.length > show_char) {
         var a = content.substr(0, show_char);
         var b = content.substr(show_char - content.length);
         var html = a + "<span class=\'truncated\'>" + ellipses + "<a class=\'read-more\'>Read more</a></span><span class=\'truncated\' style=\'display:none\'>" + b + "</span>";
         $(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description").html(html);
      }
      $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description .truncated").toggle();
      });
   ');
}
```

Source: [WooCommerce: Truncate Short Description With “Read More” Toggle](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-truncate-short-description-with-read-more-toggle/)

---

Nothing seems to be happening to the product description from the code above. Would someone be able to point out where I might be going wrong with this?

Development website

http://shop.thedevelop.co.uk/product/shampoo/

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, the problem is with your theme(builder) overriding the default WooCommerce HTML

Comment: How would I go about making this work on the builder then?

Comment: Replace  `$(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description")` with  `$(".et_pb_module_inner")`(3 times). Other adjustments (if necessary) you will have to apply on your website itself. Stack overflow is there to help with specific programming problems. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) -- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be doing anything for me when I change the targeted class. What would be my next option to go about making this work?

Comment: I already indicated to adjust this **3x**, you have only adjusted this **1x**. I also indicated that since you are not using a standard theme you will have to test/write this yourself, as this is not a global or general answer that will work for everyone 
and therefore also untestable for those who do not use the same theme as yours

Comment: Ah that was my bad. I missed that It needed adding multiple times. It seems to be working for me now which is great! Thank you for the guidance. I'm still having an issue where the code only applies to the first paragraph rather than the last one unfortunately. Do you know whether there is a quick fix for this?